# priority_queue of vectors in increasing order

Tags: c++, priority-queue

I'm trying to build a priority_queue of vectors in increasing order of the first element in each vector, in C++. Could someone help me with this? I can use a normal priority_queue with all vector elements in negative sign but is there some other way to do that?
Thanks already :)

Comment: `std::vector` have [relational operators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp) so all you have to do is to decide if you want the queue to use the [less than](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) (which is the default) or the [greater than](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater) relation. [A `std::priority_queue` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) might also come in handy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass it a different comparator. The default is `std::less`, but here you'll want `std::greater`, for example:

```
#include <functional>

typedef std::vector<int> ItemType;

std::priority_queue<
  ItemType,                                      // Type of items
  std::priority_queue<ItemType>::container_type, // Type of container
  std::greater<ItemType>                         // Comparison functor
  >
  my_queue;
```

Notice the [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1276993/14637) in the second template argument to avoid copying the default value.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Thomas, this was of great help :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use `std::greater` or lambda function.

```
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::greater<int>>
        pq(data.begin(), data.end());
```

Or

```
auto cmp = [](int left, int right) { return left < right; };
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, decltype(cmp)> pq(cmp);
```

Comment: Worth noting that from C++20 the argument for `pq` is unnecessary, since stateless lambdas became default-constructible.